# Deploy nodejs from CI server to production

Tags: node.js, devops

I have a CI server which handle to build the node app. It's separated. And once the build is done I want to deploy my node app to the production server. But I have to deploy the node modules as well.
Ofcourse I can run `npm install` command on the remote server, but it makes the production server to "work" on something that is else of serving the app.

How can I deploy nodejs bundle to production server without bringing all of the node modules, but just a prepared bundle?

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you specify the CI server you are using, so one can easily help?

Comment: Its just a node server with express. Running on `ci-server.domain.ext`, listens for pushes coming from GitHub and handle the continues integration and deployment. No Jenkins in here or CircleCI.

Comment: Does the server have a config file or where you can specify pre-deploy/pre-build commands?

Comment: The CI server you mean? Yes it has a config file.

Comment: Bundling node_modules would be a bad idea. The best would still be running `npm install` on the server

Comment: Probably, thats what I did.